# Help to solve an ODE asymptotically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Consider the following ode for $x\rightarrow\infty$

$$\left(x f(x)^3 \left(\frac{(x f^\prime)^\prime}{x}\right)^\prime\right)^\prime=0$$

Assume the function $f(x)>0$ with $x>0$ and introduce an asymptotic expansion for $x\rightarrow\infty$. However, a common power series expansion
$$f(x)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$$
for small $x$ may be not very useful.

It might also be easy to estimate the leading order term to be $\sim x^2$ without calculation since we have 4th-order derivative. However, how can I obtain some higher-order terms? In particular, can anyone please give me some hints about how to obtain the following result as $x\rightarrow\infty$:

$$f(x)\sim c x^2+\frac{3}{80c^2}\ln^2x+ O(\ln x),$$
where $c$ and $d$ are constants. **I am wondering if it is possible to obtain such a result including $\ln x$-terms with an asymptotic expansion including power functions only?**

Comment: Your formula at the moment is ambiguous. Is $y$ the same as $f$? Is the $f^3$ stand-alone, in the sense of $xf(x)^3(...)'$? And what do you mean with "asymptotic expansion", usually this is the behavior for $x\to\infty$? Then the power series expansion at $x=0$ is not very useful.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you for the comments! I have updated the post.

Comment: Where does the formula come from? The remainder is supposed to be $o(ln(x))$?

Comment: When you fully expand all the derivatives, you can see that this ODE is
$$xy^{(4)}y^3+2y^{(3)}y^3-\frac{y^3y^{(2)}}{x}+\frac{y^3y^{(1)}}{x^2}-\frac{3y^2(y^{(1)})^2}{x}+3xy^{(3)}y^2y^{(1)}+3y^2y^{(1)}y^{(2)}=0$$
When $x$ is very big, the dominant terms are clearly the ones with the highest powers of $x$, so 
$$xy^{(4)}y^3+3xy^{(3)}y^2y'\sim 0 \\ \text{as}~ x\to\infty$$
Divide through by $xy^2$,
$$y''''y^3+3y'''y'=0$$
Maybe this is useful?

Comment: Quick note: Since it's a fourth order ODE, only one of asymptotic solution might (and probably will) have a leading order term $cx^2$. In particular, this ODE has solutions(!) $f=$ const., which are obivously constant as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @dennis_s exactly, I am trying to find a non-trivial asymptotic solution.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you for your time. A side note, the notation of $F(x, y, ...)\sim 0$ may not be appropriate. Because $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to x_0$ means $\lim_{x\to x_0} f/g=1$. I think it could be better to change "$\sim$" to "$\to$".